# Python Django Public and Enterprise Users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-allauth

I am trying to build a django app with two types of users, public users that log in with facebook and enterprise users who log in with email/password. I currently am using allauth with a custom user model that lets public users log in with facebook but I am lost as to what approach I should take with creating this new enterprise user type.

There have been suggestions that I should subtype the custom user model such as in http://michalcodes4life.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/multiple-user-types-in-django-1-6/ however, this example does a poor job of showing how to integrate this with socialauth. How do I tell if the users logged in from the main page, which suggests I should make a public user, versus from the corporate log in, in which case I should make an enterprise user. How do I even specific two different reroutes depending on signup/login from different starting pages?

Other options like creating different UserProfile models seem to defeat the point of me making the custom user model to begin with. Also doesn't having a separate UserProfile model slow down DB searches? Also, I would still have to have two separate UserProfile types for public and enterprise users so I would still run into the same problem as with the first option so I might as well just subtype the custom users instead of adding to the mess with UserProfiles. Again, the problem of how to specify different redirects after signup and specify which type of user to create still exists.

The last option seems to be to use the admin system in Django for enterprise accounts. However, wouldn't this mean I would have to make the admin system UI presentable? Also, these enterprise accounts should not have access to the ability to edit users fields, so their permissions would be restricted to solely viewing public users on the site.